# How to use subplot in this for loop to display multiple pictures in single figure?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

This is my code. I want to display multiple images using Matplotlib `subplot`. The code is about splitting an image into 4 parts. Then I want to show the image parts, but this code shows them one after the other.

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

im = cv2.imread("D:\\joker.jpg")
imgheight=im.shape[0]
imgwidth=im.shape[1]

y1 = 0
M = imgheight//2
N = imgwidth//2

for y in range(0,imgheight,M):
    for x in range(0, imgwidth, N):
        y1 = y + M
        x1 = x + N
        tiles = im[y:y+M,x:x+N]

        # cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x1, y1), (0, 255, 0))
        gg =cv2.cvtColor(tiles, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # cv2.imwrite("save" + str(x) + '_' + str(y)+".png",tiles)

        plt.imshow(gg)
        plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must actually use the [`subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) command before every image to be shown. Also, it might be beneficial to move the `plt.show()` outside the nested loop.

Here would be my solution for a modified code of yours:

```py
k = 0                                                   # Initialize subplot counter
for y in range(0,imgheight,M):
    for x in range(0, imgwidth, N):
        k += 1
        y1 = y + M
        x1 = x + N
        tiles = im[y:y+M,x:x+N]
        gg =cv2.cvtColor(tiles, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        plt.subplot(2, 2, k)                            # Address proper subplot in 2x2 array
        plt.imshow(gg)
        plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()                                              # Moved plt.show() outside the loop
```

That's the output for my standard test image:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!